# Tomcat's CLASSPATH is different than Java's, and it does not include "." How do I change it?

Tags: java, tomcat, classpath, noclassdeffounderror

I've been spending hours trying to figure out why I've been getting the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`, and I've narrowed down the cause to Tomcat's classpath.

I used the code below to see what the path variables hold:

```
out.println("Classpath: '" + System.getProperty( "java.class.path" ) + "'" );
out.println("Ext dirs: '" + System.getProperty( "java.ext.dirs" ) + "'" );
out.println("Library path: '" + System.getProperty( "java.library.path" ) + "'" );
out.println("Path separator: '" + System.getProperty( "path.separator" ) + "'" );
```

And the output is:

```
Classpath: ':/usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar'
Ext dirs: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.16/jre/lib/ext:/usr/java/packages/lib/ext'
Library path: '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.16/jre/lib/i386/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.16/jre/lib/i386:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.16/jre/../lib/i386:/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib'
Path separator: ':'
```

As you can see, Classpath does NOT start with "." as it's supposed to, and I believe that's why my program can't find the classes that I import from subdirectories in my webapp.

To see where the classpath is set, i did `grep -R bootstrap.jar /usr/local/tomcat/`, and came accross this: `CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH":"$CATALINA_HOME"/bin/bootstrap.jar` (in file `/usr/local/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh`)

This makes me believe that for some reason $CLASSPATH is empty here. However, `echo $CLASSPATH` successfully returns `.:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin:/usr/local/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar`

Can anybody help pin down the problem here?

---

EDIT: All my servlet files are in `WEB-INF/classes/controllers/`, and the libraries i'm trying to load are class files in subdirectories. 
For example, if `ClassName.class` is in the WEB-INF/classes/controllers/packagename/ directory, I add `package packagename` to the start of `ClassName.java`, and I import it using `import packagename.*` in `someServlet.java`.

---

EDIT2: I have solved my problem. My main issue was that, as written below, not using the correct package names. Also, I was trying to compile from inside the `classes/controllers/` directory, instead of compiling from `classes/`. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 7):

Classes required in a web application should be located within the web application in the WEB-INF/classes folder or packed in JAR files located in WEB-INF/lib. You should normally not use the servlet containers generic classpath settings for this, as you seem to attempt.

Comment: all my servlets are in WEB-INF/classes/controllers, and the classes i'm trying to load are *.class files in subdirectories.

my issue is that since "." doesn't appear to be in my web app's classpath, loading libraries from subdirectories does not work.

Comment: The correct package for a class file located in WEB-INF/classes/controllers/packagename/ClassName.class would be "controllers.packagename" and not "packagename" as your question seem to imply. You cannot have additional subdirectories below WEB-INF/classes as class path roots and the system properties or environment variables are in a web application not evaluated by the class loader as they are in a standalone appplication.

Comment: . would likely refer to the startup script of tomcat, not the webapp.

Answer (score 7):

Tomcat's classpath is not supposed to be starting with `.`. Actually, adding `.` to the classpath is just a convenient way to tell java to look for classes in the current directory without having to use `-cp` when using it on the command line.

Actually, in most case, you don't have to tweak Tomcat's classpath. To make Tomcat able to find your classes, what you need to do is to deploy your application as a standardized WAR (web archive) which has a specific layout. Something like that:

```
.
|-- WEB-INF
|   |-- classes
|   |   `-- com
|   |       `-- mycompany
|   |           `-- MyServlet.class
|   |-- lib
|   |   |-- bar.jar
|   |   `-- foo.jar
|   `-- web.xml
|-- application.jsp
|-- image.gif
`-- index.html
```

The `WEB-INF/classes` directory is where your compiled classes need to be, this is where Tomcat will look for them. If you place your classes in `WEB-INF/classes/controllers`, `controllers` will be considered as part of the package name (which is likely not what you want). So you have two options:

1. remove that `controllers` directory
2. or add it to the package name.

But they are mutually exclusive, you can't have both.

Answer (score 2):

`CLASSPATH` is *not* "supposed" to start with `"."`. Since its purpose is configuration of the runtime, it is free to take on any value you choose. Also note that using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable has been discouraged since Java 1.1 (released in early 1997)—at least 12 years.

The classpath of a web-application, on the other hand is well-specified. Move the *contents* of the `controllers` directory (and any other invalid subdirectories) into `WEB-INF/classes/`, so that the package directory is an immediate child of `classes`.